# GameCenter Report Score - Local declaration hides instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I'm adding Game Center functionality to my app, and I have run into something strange that I can't get my head around...

I've used this exact method (and code) in 5 games, so I can't see why it's throwing a warning message now...

I get 2x "local declaration of 'score' hides instance variable" in the `ReportScore` method...

[image: Warnings]

The code is as follows:

```
-(void)reportScore{
    GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
    score.value = gameScore; //gameScore is games Score that needs submitting

    [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

I've tried declaring the variable like this in the `.h`:

```
    @property (nonatomic) GKScore *score;
```

But that introduces an `autosynthesised` warning instead... I don't understand why this is happening when it doesn't do this in any other apps of mine?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I did this... It shows how easy it is to miss things when you're staring at code so long...

It turns out, I have a `UIImageView` with the name `score`...

```
.h
IBOutlet UIImageView *score;
```

Simply changing the `GKScore` variable name, the warnings disappeared...

```
-(void)reportScore{
    GKScore *this_score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
    this_score.value = gameScore;

    [GKScore reportScores:@[this_score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"Reported to Game Center...");
}
```

What a doughnut!